# convert java object from sql to xml

Tags: xml

Is there a way or a function in java where java can create several xml documents for each customer that i am queering from a sql db?

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT (sqlstuff), (sqlstuff) , (sqlstuff) , (sqlstuff) , (sqlstuff) ,(sqlstuff) , (sqlstuff) , " +
            "(sqlstuff) , (sqlstuff) , (sqlstuff) , (sqlstuff) , (sqlstuff) , (sqlstuff) , (sqlstuff) , (sqlstuff#), (sqlstuff#) OST00008 FROM filetype");

```
  ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you this clean way:

- Define your Customer class in java
- Create a list of Customer from database rows
- Convert your list of Customer in xml (using Jaxb for example)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing I've found was to use an ORM tool like Hibernate to map the objects into a database for me, and then use JAXB as well. I'd put the Hibernate annotations on the object's fields, and the XML annotations on the object's property getters, and I had to write almost no serialization code for either, only what was required to integrate with the two frameworks.